# SocketIO & ReactJs: Message is getting emitted multiple times from server to frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am making a chatroom application using reactjs(socketIo) and nodeJs. When I emit the message from frontend to server, it gets emitted only once, but when I emit it back from server to frontend, It gets emitted multiple times.

Frontend Code:

```
function handleChat(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("newMessage", { message: msg, user: props.user.name });
    setMsg("");
  }
    socket.on("messageList", (list) => {
      console.log(list.message);
      var allMsg = messages
      allMsg.push({message: list.message.message, name: list.message.user})
      setMessages(allMsg);
  })
```

In the code above `newMessage` is the handler for emitting the message from frontend to server and `messageList` is the handler for message from the server(which is the issue).

Backend Code:

```
namespace.forEach((ns) => {
    io.of(`/${ns.name}`).on("connect", (socket1) => {
      // console.log(ns.name, socket1.id);
      socket1.on("name",(name)=>{
        console.log(name);
      })
      socket1.on("newMessage", (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        io.of(`/${ns.name}`).emit("messageList",{message})
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: looks like you're adding multiple listeners for "newMessage" - one for each namespace in `namespace` array.

Comment: @tromgy that might not be the case. Because the loop you are talking about is for different rooms and also the number of sockets emitting back are not consistent like number of rooms. At the moment there are only 3 rooms, and the socket is emitting sometimes 20 times, sometimes 30 times.